# want to run jquery one time on multiple reload

Tags: jquery

I have a form with 5 steps, page get reload on each step.
on the first step I have a dropdown to select number of people `i.e 1, 2, 3, 4, 6`
on second steps where I am calculating price with the multiplication of previous dropdown selected value:

```
var dd = jQuery("#input_8_141 option:selected").val();
var ki = parseInt(jQuery("#input_8_285").val());
var tot = dd*ki;
jQuery("#input_8_285").val(Number(tot));
```

now if i go to third step then the total get multiply again by selected dropdown value.
so if i selected 2 from drop down then on the third step total is `tot x 2 x 2`

So I do not want to multiply `tot` on each step rather than step 2.

Let me know if I missed something to elaborate my issue.
I will appreciate all helps.

TIA

Comment: are all these five forms in same page?

Comment: yes, I m using gravity multi step form...

Comment: add an event when the second form is visible (with jquery :visible property) and place the above script inside it.

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mcve] that reproduces the issue